rename package in android studio recreate me a new package
upload package issue android studio
hello please check the image i have an issue when i do uncheck compact middle package and after do a refactor-> rename packages it's not updating the package but recreate me a new folder with the new changed name .how to solve it thanks

In Java, packages are directly mapped to folders so when a package is renamed the corresponding folder would be renamed or a new folder created.

OK thanks for the update now do ineed to delete the old folder packages.

its not updating all the files in the new package

i found the issue you just need to go in android studio File-> Repair IDE.

if its not working just refactor->rename it will create anew package then file->repair ide
